# add prefix to asterisk inbound trunk on certain conditions

Tags: asterisk

the task is quite simple, but i have not figured it out yet.

one trunk has a local number in germany .. 
so if someone from germany calls the CID is the number without the Country code.
but if somone from outside calls, the country code comes with the CID (which is totally fine if you are located within germany)

my outgoing rules are use the countrycode 0049 to select the voip trunk the call comes from.
but since the 0049 is not come along for inbound calls .. it will never beeing selected .. and you have to manually edit the number (which is a pain on a analog phone) and often forgotten by mistake.

is there a possibility to siimply have the inbound CID remodeled

like this:

- if the inbound CID is _00. then just forward the CID to the ring group
- if the Inbound CID is _0Z. then remove the first digit (the 0) from the original CID, prefix 0049 and send to the ring group.

any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route your trunk to a custom start context and do the normalization there. Example:

```
[globals]
LOCAL_PREFIX=511  ; Hannover local prefix for example

; trunk A starts here
[inbound_trunk_A]
; 123 is your extension, everything after "/" is an extension filter on CALLERID(num)
exten => 123/_00X.,1,NoOp(CallerID is just fine)
exten => 123/_0ZX.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=0049${CALLERID(num):1})
exten => 123/_ZX.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=0049${LOCAL_PREFIX}${CALLERID(num)})
; after CallerID normalization, jump to the real context
exten => 123,2,Goto(real_context,${EXTEN},1)

; all other trunks start here
[real_context]
exten => 123,1,DoRingGroupStuff()
```

Comment: thats just great (sorry for the late response) ... nut how do i "bind" this rules on a certain Trunk only (inbound) ?

Comment: @Nullx8 via contexts .. route this certain trunk to a specific context and do the normalization there ... I'll update my post to reflect what i mean.

Comment: i did add it like this  exten=s/_0ZX.,2,Set(CALLERID(num)=0049${${CALLERID(num)}:1}) but it does alter the number to JUST "0049" .. which is odd

Comment: one $ too much this did it .. exten=s/_0ZX.,2,Set(CALLERID(num)=0049${CALLERID(num):1})

now calls from the German Trunk are properly marked with German Country code, thanks alot for the hint